# Apache web server 404 error

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I just created an HTML file and saved it in  /var/www/HTML. The HTML file is supposed to display a jpg image file located in the same folder, but it does not. Whenever I click on the image it gives 404 error image not found in the folder. Please help fast.Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page 1 </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/
bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
.navbar{
margin-bottom:0;
border-radius:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar" style="background:#33194d;>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">StartDirect</a>
</div>
<div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container-fluid">
<img src="/var/www/html/page1.jpeg"style="width:100%;height:auto;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deHrV.png)

Comment: Is it calling the image on the same folder? What's the URL for the image?

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: Show your HTML code and what URL are you taken to when you click on the image?

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly help @Havenard

Comment: there you go @hcheung

Comment: Code and images now available @Kita

Comment: Does it work when using relative paths instead of absolute? Means in this case just `page1.jpeg` instead of the fill path as image src.

Comment: 404 is a **server** error, the problem is that the file you're trying to point at simply _doesn't exist_ meaning your URL is incorrect, not necessarily the code in the file.

Comment: If your server is setup correct with DocumentRoot as var/www/html, then all you need is `<img src="page1.jpeg">`, not `<img src="/var/www/html/page1.jpeg">`. You need to have a better understanding of [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Answer (score 2):

As if you are running this on the server. Port 80, it will be Localhost/{yourhtml}.

Now you need to understand the path, that how on the server it needs to be declared. When running on the system, your path start from the root directory which is by default is your home directory. Now when you are on server it's root directory  at localhost which is pointing the path

> /var/www/html/

And whatever you put inside that folder it will address from this path.

So as you are using

```
<img src="/var/www/html/page1.jpeg"style="width:100%;height:auto;">
```

**Now browser will understand it as**

> /var/www/html/var/www/html/page1.jpeg

**Where no such directory exist**

**simply use**

```
<img src="page1.jpeg"style="width:100%;height:auto;">`
```

Again it will point the path if your image file is inside the HTML

> /var/www/html/page1.jpeg

else If you are having any folder suppose *Image* and your image file inside that image folder. you just now need to address the folder also

```
<img src="Image/page1.jpeg"style="width:100%;height:auto;">`
```

> /var/www/html/Image/page1.jpg

Comment: The question looks so stupid now. Thanks, @satyam Pathak

Comment: your welcome, accept it if it works for you :) @PrashantChamoli